# How can I control the planar traits of a certain spot, and make it any trait I want?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes

I want to gain some benefits from the traits of other planes, without leaving my home plane.

How can I control the planar traits of a certain spot, and make it any trait I want?

Being able to turn it on and off and also change which traits from time to time is ideal.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, mimichan! Check out the [tour] and the [help] to learn more about the site!

Answer (score 12):

**Planar Bubble** (Clr7/Wiz7 spell, source: Spell Compendium) copies all planar traits from target creature's native plane. Area: 10-foot-radius, mobile; duration: 10 minutes per casterlevel.

**Planar Bubble** (Planar Shepherd classfeature, ECL 10, source: Faiths of Eberron) same as the spell, except that a Planar Shepherd can only cast it on herself, and thus can't pick a different plane each time. Area: 20-foot-radius, mobile; duration: concentration + 1d10 rounds.

**Orrery of the Planes** (item, 50,000gp, source: Eberron Campaign Setting) copies one magic trait from any outer plane. Area: 60-foot-radius, stationary while in use; duration: no maximum duration, can be turned on an off.

**Anchor Plane** (Psion8 power, source: Faiths of Eberron) copies one planar trait from any plane. Area: 150-foot-radius, stationary; duration: permanent.

**Intensify Manifest Zone** (Clr7/Druid7/Psion7, source: Faiths of Eberron) permanently adds one more planar trait to an existing manifest zone, such as the one created by Anchor Plane or Orrery of the Planes.

**Precipitate Breach** (Wiz5 spell, source: Planar Handbook) copies one alignment, elemental/energy, or magic trait... Unfortunately, you can't pick from which plane, it's just random. Area: 10d10-foot-radius, stationary; duration: 1d6 days.

**Precipitate Complete Breach** (Wiz9 spell, source: Planar Handbook) creates an inter-planar portal whose surroundings (on both ends) are affected by all traits from both planes... Unfortunately, you still can't pick the destination, it's just random. Area: 10d10-foot-radius, stationary; duration: 1d6 days.

**Acorn of Far Travel** (Druid2/Ranger2 spell, source: [web](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101204231/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fw/20040710a&pf=true)) is probably not intended to interact with planar travel, the spell's author clearly didn't consider it. But a literal reading of "As long as you carry the acorn, you are considered to be standing under that oak tree's canopy (and thus within an area of forested terrain)." might imply that you're subject to the planar traits of wherever the tree is, too. Area: self-only, mobile; duration: 1 day per casterlevel.

**Portal Seepage** (source: FRCS and PGtF for how to craft permanent portals, and Underdark for the seepage effect) Sufficiently old portals may transmit planar traits from one side to the other. The books treat this as an undesired but common side-effect, and don't provide any rules for hurrying it up on purpose. Area: typically 5-foot-radius per 100 years of age, stationary; duration: permanent.

Comment: Huh, never heard of most of these, nice finds. Can’t believe I forgot the damn *acorn of far travel*.

Comment: The Godly Realm rules (especially if you have 16+ ranks) can also accomplish this. https://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineRanksAndPowers.htm  You can get divine ranks via *Ice Assassin*, particularly if you are Pun-Pun, but also gods have them and maybe this should be included for completeness.

Comment: You can also take a look at the substituion levels in the _Planar Handbook_, especially: _Planar Discordance_ (bard, 12th level) wich lets you create a planar breach as with the _precipitate breach_ spell, and _Enhanced Magic_ (wizard, 14th level) which enhances your spells as if cast on a different plane.

Answer (score 3):

What you’re looking for is the planar bubble ability of a 5th-level planar shepherd. Once per day (3/day at 10th level), the planar shepherd can give a 20-ft. radius bubble the traits of their chosen plane, which lasts as long as they concentrate (up to an hour/level) plus 1d10 rounds thereafter.

The plane whose traits you use is fixed when you enter the planar shepherd class, so you won’t be able to change the traits after that.

This is the only ability of this sort that I’m aware of. It’s eminently abusable, so planar shepherd shows up in a lot of theoretical optimization exercises. Planar shepherd is also one of the only prestige classes in the game that advance all of a druid’s major class features.

Planar shepherd is found in *Faiths of Eberron*, and requires wild shape, one of two feats (which each require spontaneously casting *summon nature’s ally*), and some skill ranks (8 in Knowledge (religion) and 4 in Knowledge (the planes)). These requirements mean that a 5th-level planar shepherd is a 10th-level character overall, so the ability is not available before that (barring major cheese, but then again we’re talking about the planar shepherd so maybe that point is moot).